# How should "Typo in code" questions be reviewed/edited?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630813/cocos2d-self-touchenabled-yes-not-found) is just a typo in code. Using Stack Overflow as spell check seems completely wrong. I would consider the question to be unsalvageable in the sense that it will likely never provide any value to other users. How should it be flagged during review?

Comment: Flag the question as off-topic as _no longer reproducible because of a simple typo ..._

Comment: I did not realize there was a second level of options under the off-topic selection.

Comment: Flag options ending with a "..." in the list have other options under them, for your future reference.